# Uniform conversion of numeric values to JSON

Tags: json, r

I'm trying to convert a data.table object to JSON. The columns, which have `numeric` values, should be converted to JSON values in an "uniform" way, i.e. all values should contain the decimal part, even if it's ".0". What I have is:

```
library(RJSONIO)
test <- data.table(V1 = c(1.0, 2.0, 4.5, 3.0))
cat(toJSON(test))

{
  "V1": [ 1,  2,  4.5,  3 ] 
}
```

However, what I'm trying to do is getting the following output:

```
{
  "V1": [ 1.0,  2.0,  4.5,  3.0 ] 
}
```

I've tried with other libraries such as `rjson` and I'm getting the same result. I can't seem to find any option that would control this. My last option would be to manually process the output the JSON string, adding the required ".0"s at the end, but I'm wondering if there is a better option. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? When parsed, `1` and `1.0` in the JSON won't produce any difference, I guess.

Comment: @nicola Because I want to put the JSON in Elasticsearch (using the `elastic` library) and if the array doesn't have the numbers in the same "format", Elasticsearch keeps getting me annoying errors of "mapper [V1] of different type, current_type [long], merged_type [double]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jsonlite` has an `always_decimal` option for this:

```
> test <- data.table(V1 = c(1.0, 2.0, 4.5, 3.0))
> test
    V1
1: 1.0
2: 2.0
3: 4.5
4: 3.0
> jsonlite::toJSON(test,  dataframe="columns", always_decimal=TRUE)
{"V1":[1.0,2.0,4.5,3.0]}
```

It doesn't seem to be strictly "always":

```
> test$V2 = 1:4
> jsonlite::toJSON(test,  dataframe="columns", always_decimal=TRUE)
{"V1":[1.0,2.0,4.5,3.0],"V2":[1,2,3,4]}
```

but it looks like it does do some inspection of the column types:

```
> test$V3 = c(1,2,3,4.0)
> jsonlite::toJSON(test,  dataframe="columns", always_decimal=TRUE)
{"V1":[1.0,2.0,4.5,3.0],"V2":[1,2,3,4],"V3":[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]}
```

and does decimals for "numeric" and not "integer" columns.

Comment: Great! I didn't pay attention to that library. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The following code does exactly what you want using **format** and  **round** to specify the number of decimal places:

```
     library(RJSONIO)
     library(data.table)

     test <- data.table(V1 = c(1.0, 2.0, 4.5, 3.0))
     test$V1 <- format(round(test$V1, 2))
     cat(toJSON(test))
```

results :

```
{
 "V1": [ "1.0", "2.0", "4.5", "3.0" ] 
}
```

Comment: Except it converts the numbers to quoted string values. If the goal is to feed these to ElasticSearch as numerics, then some other munging may be needed.

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman, I guess I'll have to use `gsub` and a good old regex after all.

Comment: Errr no :) after struggling to see if I could define an asJSON method for a new class that presented with decimals, the solution appeared... See my answer!